# Linq query for not in operator

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I have a sql query. I need a linq query for that.

```
select rightname 
from IB_Right_Master 
where id not in (select RightID from IB_Group_Rights where GroupID = '3');
```

Table : RightMaster

```
ID   |   RightName   |  RightGroupName       |
----------------------------------------------
1    |    Test       |   Add Group Users     |
2    |  Add Group    |   Page Access rights  |
3    |  Page Access  |   Group deletion      |
3    |  Delete Group |   Group deletion      | 
----------------------------------------------
```

Table : Group Rights

```
ID   |   RightID    |      GroupID         |      Status   |
------------------------------------------------------------
1    |    1         |        1             |      True     |
2    |    1         |        2             |      True     |
3    |    2         |        3             |      True     |
4    |    3         |        4             |      True     |
5    |    1         |        3             |      True     |
------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: first you edit your question properly

Comment: `where id not in (select id from IB_Group_Rights where id = '1'); ` Is the same as just writing `where id != '1'`

Comment: `select id from 
IB_Group_Rights where id = '1'`... ???

Comment: @kyle I changed the query.

Comment: Please post code demonstrating a good faith attempt to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var data = (from m in db.IB_Right_Master                
           where m.Id != 1
           select m.RightName).ToList();
```

Comment: this is not giving multiple recodrs

Comment: if you check for group id 3 ,it is not giving exact right name which one is not assign to group 3.query is giving wrong output for group 3

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
var lst = IB_Right_Master.Where(x => !IB_Group_Rights.Any(y => x.id==y.RightID && y.id==1))
                         .Select(x => x.rightname).ToList();
```

Comment: It is saying operand && can not applied to operends of type int

Comment: No we have to use "==" not "=". I edited my post, now also the same query in my post throwing same error?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
var result = from m in db.IB_Right_Master                
             where IB_Group_Rights.Any(r => r.RightID != 1 && r.RightID == m.Id)
             select m.RightName
```

Comment: Any keyword is giving error for model IB_Group_Rights